# Editing .htaccess file (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, settings

I need to edit my .htaccess file for my WordPress site, and I need to have these settings:

```
max_execution_time 360           
memory_limit 128M        
post_max_size 32M       
upload_max_filesize 32M        
max_input_vars 5000
```

I don't edit the .htaccess file a lot, so can someone help me out with this? I need these settings, but in the format that I can put in the .htaccess file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can set the `php.ini` option through `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_execution_time 360           
php_value memory_limit 128M        
php_value post_max_size 32M       
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M        
php_value max_input_vars 5000   
</IfModule>
```

Hope this help !

Comment: Thanks!, you rock!

Comment: @BrianSchnurr kindly mark this as answer if it works :)